# could not get updated shard list from config server due to Operation timed out

Tags: mongodb

> mongodb:v3.4.9

error logs from mongodb c++ source code: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/367d31e1da549c460ae710a8cc280f4c235ab24f/src/mongo/s/client/shard_registry.cpp#L384

Mongos throw error when i add new node to a shard cluster and all the enableShardCollection can't query (*ExceededTimeLimit*).

It's can be repaired?

> Marking host  config.app.com as failed :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 871 -- target:config.app.com db:config expDate:2017-10-21T13:16:38.250+0000 cmd:{ find: "shards", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1508586527000|1, t: 24 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
>
> 2017-10-21T13:16:38.250+0000 I SHARDING [shard registry reload] Operation timed out  :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 871 -- target:config.app.com db:config expDate:2017-10-21T13:16:38.250+0000 cmd:{ find: "shards", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1508586527000|1, t: 24 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
>
> 2017-10-21T13:16:38.250+0000 I SHARDING [shard registry reload] Periodic reload of shard registry failed  :: caused by :: 50 could not get updated shard list from config server due to Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 871 -- target:config.app.com db:config expDate:2017-10-21T13:16:38.250+0000 cmd:{ find: "shards", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1508586527000|1, t: 24 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }; will retry after 30s

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and after hours of debugging I found that my config server was started without the `configsvr: true` option in `rs.initiate`. So mongos was requesting data from my config server but the config server didn't know how to respond. fwiw, I had

```
sharding: 
    clusterRole: configsvr
```

in my conf file but looks like that wasn't picked up.